# Accept arbitrary multi-line input of String type and store it in a variable

Tags: java, python, input, java.util.scanner

Is there any possible way to accept a **arbitrary(unknown)** no. of input lines of string from the user until  user explicitly enters **-1** and **store it in a string** for further manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather, you're trying to get input from a user until that user types `-1`. If thats the case, please see my function below.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    // Scanner is used for I/O
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Prompt user to enter text
    System.out.println("Enter something ");

    // Get input from scanner by using next()
    String text = input.next();

    // this variable is used to store all previous entries
    String storage = "";

        // While the user does not enter -1, keep receiving input
        // Store user text into a running total variable (storage)
        while (!text.equals("-1")) {
            System.out.println("You entered: " + text);
            text = input.next();
            storage = storage + "\n" + text
    }
}
```

I've left comments in that code block but I'll reiterate it here. First we declare our I/O object so that we can get input from the keyboard. We then ask the user to `"Enter something"` and wait for the user to enter something. This process is repeated in the while loop **until** the user specifically types `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes no sense... You're talking about taking input from a user, but also reaching the end of a file, implying you are taking reading input from a file. Which is it?

If you're trying to say that for each line in a file, the user must enter something for some action to be taken, then yes, that can be done.

I'll assume you already have a File object or String containing the file path, named `file`.

```
// make a stream for the file
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
// make a stream for the console
BufferedReader consoleReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
// declare a String to store the file input
String fileInput;
// use a StringBuilder to construct the user input lines
StringBuilder inputLines = new StringBuilder();
// while there is a line to be read
while ((fileInput = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
    /*
    ** maybe some output here to instruct the user?
    */
    // get some input from the user
    String userInput = consoleReader.readLine();
    // if the user wants to stop
    if (userInput.equals("-1")) {
        // exit the loop
        break;
    }
    // else append the input
    inputLines.append(userInput+"\r\n");
}
// close your streams
fileReader.close();
consoleReader.close();
// perform your further manipulation
doSomething(inputLines.toString());
```

Those classes are located in `java.io.*`. Also, remember to catch or have your method throw `IOException`.

If you want to perform your manipulation each time you have some input instead of doing it all at the end, get rid of the `StringBuilder`, and move `doSomething(userInput)` into the loop before the if statement.